# Reactjs Nominatim API-Cors

Tags: api, reactjs, cors, nominatim

I would like to implement the Nominatim API using ReactJS. When I request the URL, I get the following error:

> A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of an XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

After some research, I discovered that I must use CORS to access the data. So I edited the header in the Webpack config. On the server where I run my app, the code is the following:

```
devServer: {
      headers: {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Authorization, x-id, Content-Length, X-Requested-With",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
},  
  inline: true,
  port: 8080
```

}

But it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

try testing it from a production server

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the above configuration in production, you are putting your server wide open on the internet, these are no the safest to config for production.

You can fix that in `reactjs` directly, by adding

```json
"proxy": "http://localhost:8080"
```

in your `package.json` file of your react project.

I have wrote a complete article about it, where you can check it and understand more https://minasami.com/2021/06/10/cors-errors-fix-with-reactjs.html